# C#.net DLL COM wrapper and installation

Tags: c#, dll

I'm making a load of code bits that will eventually be used in another C# program long term, but I may want to use it in various other apps, and I need to use it easily now as it gradually develops. So I've written a few C#.net DLLs in Visual Studio Express 2017. Two of which reference a 3rd-party DLL (one of which was installed by other software, one of which I just pointed at in Visual Studio), and one of my DLLs references my other 2 DLLs. I've ticked the boxes to COM register my ones and I'm now happily using them from Excel/VBA.

But how do I install it on another Win10 machine in simple steps though, so I can use the same spreadsheets and automation on those computers? (preferably with some explanation of what the steps are actually doing?) I haven't had any luck with the other options I've googled, maybe they're not "idiot proof" enough for me, or my DLLs have dependencies on other DLLs, or I'm getting them from the wrong place.

- I assume these are 64-bit DLLs (they're complied for 'Any CPU') so I
  want to copy them into the 64-bit place (syswow64)? Or should they go
  in system32 as well?
- I guess I get them from my 'release', not 'debug' folders?
- I also have .pdb and .tlb  as well as .dll. Do I need these? Maybe they're the missing piece of the jigsaw?
- What's the difference between regsvr and regasm and what should I be using? (Or both).
- Also is there a simple way to make a DLL copying and COM registering installer app? And if yes, does that still apply if it's VS Express
  2017?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The simplest way is add entry in the windows registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Namespace.ClassName\CLSID` with default value of `{CLSID}` and then `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{CLSID}` or `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CLSID}` with right values

Comment: I don't know if Express Edition has the 'Installer Project' type by default, your best option is to create an installer that will handle the proper registrations in your behalf. COM is tricky and registering everything manually and get all dependencies in place is not easy. If you want to know what dependencies the 3rd Party DLLs have you can use 'Depends' from Win SDK, however, if they are native DLLs, written in VC++ for instance, you might have additional dependencies to specific VC Runtimes, and they must be installed along these dlls for them to work properly.